# On the path to No Rails Spec, how to tackle the testing of deeply nested model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2

On the path of No Rails Specs, I've only seen the examples that are given with just a single model or at most 2 associations.
I'm wondering on how to apply on the application that has deep level of nesting. So for example, following is a nested example,

```
Survey
  has_many :questions

Question
  has_many :answers

Answer
  belongs_to :user

User
  has_many :surveys
  has_many :answers
```

how to write specs, stub/mock object to test the Answer model?

The gist of my question is I always get caught while testing the lowest level of nested model.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents (as I've been working towards the same goal):

- Avoid Law of Demeter violations like the plague. The more your object delves into another object's structure, the more objects you'll have to stub/mock.
- OpenStruct is your friend!
- Whenever you need data from a deeply nested object consider two things:

  1. Write a method on the object in the middle that will return the data you want.
  2. Create an object that wraps the relation

One pattern from Avdi Grimm's *Objects on Rails* book that I've found really helpful is:

```
class YourObject
  def make_related_object
    related_object_maker.call
  end

  def related_object_maker=(maker)
    @related_object_maker = maker
  end

  private
  def related_object_maker
    @related_object_maker ||= RelatedObject.public_method(:new)
  end
end
```

This lets you replace the relation with a lambda in your tests, which is terribly convenient.

**EDIT**

```
describe YourObject do
  let(:maker) { lambda { "some value" } }
  subject { YourObject.new }

  before(:each) do
    subject.related_object_maker = maker
  end

  its(:make_related_object) { should == "some value" }
end
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot... Pull as much of your business logic out of AR models as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can u do post the testing sample code so that I could get it clear on how to make that lambda call?